# Is there an official NuGet single-string package identifier?

Tags: nuget

For a dependency management system, I'm looking to see if there is an official single-string format identifying NuGet packages, which combines package name and version. I couldn't find any information on this, the official documentation always separating the package name from the version.

I am thinking for example of what is done for Maven, npm or pip:

- Maven: `groupId:artifactId:version`
- npm: `<name>@<version>`
- pip: `name==version`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like this in the NuGet world. The used package identifier strings mostly depend on the usage and tool, e. g.:

- Package Manager → `Install-Package My.Package -Version 19.5.3`
- .NET CLI → `dotnet add package My.Package --version 19.5.3`
- `packages.config` → `<package id="My.Package" version="19.5.3" />`
- `<PackageReference>` → `<PackageReference Include="My.Package" Version="19.5.3" />`